# Getting an error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error:

> Procedure or function 'NewEmployee' expects parameter '@LastName', which was not supplied

This is what I have:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE NewEmployee1 (
     @LastName nvarchar(75)
     ,@FirstName nvarchar(50)
     ,@HireDate datetime
     ,@Birthdate datetime
     ,@Title nvarchar(30))
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN

Set NOCOUNT ON;
Begin Try
    Begin Transaction;
    INSERT INTO Employees (LastName,FirstName,HireDate,BirthDate,Title)
    VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @HireDate,@Birthdate,@Title)

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

End Try
Begin Catch
--Rollback any active or uncommitable transactions before
--inserting information in the errorLog
If @@Trancount > 0
Begin
Rollback Transaction;
End
Execute NewEmployee1 ;
End Catch;
End;

Exec NewEmployee
 @LastName = 'Halpert',
 @FirstName = 'Jim',
 @HireDate = '11/14/2011',
 @BirthDate = '04/02/1971',
 @Title = 'Sales';
```

Should I have it like @lastName nvarchar(75) = Null?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right procedure? The error message says 'NewEmployee' but your definition says 'NewEmployee1'.

Comment: Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure NewEmployee1, Line 0
Procedure or function 'NewEmployee1' expects parameter '@LastName', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the line `Execute NewEmployee1 ;` which attempts to execute the stored procedure with no parameters.

If you want default values assigned to parameters, you need to do as you suggested...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewEmployee1 (
  @LastName nvarchar(75)   = NULL
 ,@FirstName nvarchar(50)  = NULL
 ,@HireDate datetime       = NULL
 ,@Birthdate datetime      = NULL
 ,@Title nvarchar(30)      = NULL
)
```

Or replacing the NULLs with any appropriate default value.

Answer (score 3):

You define the procedure as `NewEmployee1`, but then you call `NewEmployee`.

---

EDIT:

I think that calling `Execute NewEmployee1 ;` in the `CATCH` statement could potentially cause an infinite loop if there were some problem calling the stored procedure with the default values...  Are you sure you want to call the SP again in the `CATCH`?

Comment: I change that and I forgot it put it in my code but I still get that same error

Answer (score 1):

I see

```
CREATE PROCEDURE **NewEmployee1**
```

while you later on call it using

```
Exec NewEmployee
```

withiout the 1 at the end of the name.

Probably you have another procedure NewEmployee, which does not have a param @LastName.

Comment: I already fixed all that and I am still getting the same error